# Converting em to px in Javascript (and getting default font size)

Tags: javascript, css, events, dom

There are situations where it can be useful to get the exact pixel width of an `em` measurement.  For example, suppose you have an element with a CSS property (like border or padding) which is measured in ems, and you need to get the exact pixel width of the border or padding.  There's an existing question which touches on this topic:

[How can i get default font size in pixels by using JavaScript or JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442542/how-can-i-get-default-font-size-in-pixels-by-using-javascript-or-jquery)

This question is asking about getting the *default font size* - which is necessary in order to convert a relative `em` value to an exact `px` value.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530334/168288) has a pretty good explanation of how to go about getting the default font size of an element:

> Since ems measure width you can always compute the exact pixel font
>   size by creating a div that is 1000 ems long and dividing its
>   client-Width property by 1000. I seem to recall ems are truncated to
>   the nearest thousandth, so you need 1000 ems to avoid an erroneous
>   truncation of the pixel result.

So, using this answer as a guide, I wrote the following function to get the default font size:

```
function getDefaultFontSize(parentElement)
{
    parentElement = parentElement || document.body;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = "1000em";
    parentElement.appendChild(div);
    var pixels = div.offsetWidth / 1000;
    parentElement.removeChild(div);
    return pixels;
}
```

Once you have the default font size, you can convert any `em` width to `px` width by just multiplying the ems by the element's default font size and rounding the result:

`Math.round(ems * getDefaultFontSize(element.parentNode))`

**Problem:** The `getDefaultFontSize` is ideally supposed to be a simple, side-effect free function that returns the default font size.  But it *DOES* have an unfortunate side effect: it modifies the DOM!  It appends a child and then removes the child. Appending the child is necessary in order to get a valid `offsetWidth` property.  If you don't append the child `div` to the DOM, the `offsetWidth` property remains at 0 because the element is never rendered.  Even though we immediately remove the child element, this function can still create unintended side effects, such as firing an event (like Internet Explorer's `onpropertychange` or W3C's `DOMSubtreeModified` event) that was listening on the parent element.

**Question:** Is there any way to write a truly side-effect free `getDefaultFontSize()` function that won't accidentally fire event handlers or cause other unintended side effects?

Comment: Not really, that's just how the DOM works. However you could set the class of the created element to something such as `font-size-check` and then in any events fired, check if the element has that class to determine whether or not to ignore it.

Comment: Traverse the DOM until you find a node with a width specified in ems, and use that for a somewhat less accurate measurement? The only side effect is processing time. Also it's not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Edit: No, there isn't.**

To get the rendered font size of a given element, without affecting the DOM:

```
parseFloat(getComputedStyle(parentElement).fontSize);
```

This is based off the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571813/why-is-this-javascript-function-so-slow-on-firefox).

---

**Edit:**

In IE, you would have to use `parentElement.currentStyle["fontSize"]`, but this is not guaranteed to convert the size to `px`. So that's out.

Furthermore, this snippet won't get you the default font size of the element, but rather its *actual* font size, which is important if it has actually got a class and a style associated with it. In other words, if the element's font size is `2em`, you'll get the number of pixels in 2 ems. Unless the font size is specified inline, you won't be able to get the conversion ratio right.

Comment: It won't change the DOM, but will force the browser to do a recalc/layout operation, so not a "free" operation. Also, use parseFloat() not Number()!

Comment: @ThomasMcCabe: why not use `Number()`?

Comment: well, if you use `parseFloat` you won't need the overhead of a regex as you could just do `parseFloat(getComputedStyle(parentElement, "").fontSize)`. If you tried to do the same with `Number` you'd get `NaN`. So basically, I'm saying that you're adding the overhead of `.match` for no reason. Also, `Number` in this case is marginally slower than `parseFloat`.

Comment: "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'". If anyone is getting this error when using a jQuery object as the 'parentElement': you just need to replace it with a JS element (i.e. HTML DOM object). You can do: $('#parentElement')[0].

Comment: @EnginYapici use $jQueryElememt.get(0) as first param of getComputedStyle()

Answer (score 12):

I have a better answer. My code will store the length of `1em` (in CSS pixel `px` units in the JavaScript variable `em`:

1. Place this `div` anywhere in your HTML code

   ```
   <div id="div" style="height:0;width:0;outline:none;border:none;padding:none;margin:none;box-sizing:content-box;"></div>
   ```
2. Place this function in your JavaScript file

   ```
   var em;
   function getValue(id){
       var div = document.getElementById(id);
       div.style.height = '1em';
       return ( em = div.offsetHeight );
   }
   ```

Now, whenever you will call this function `'getValue'` with id of that test div in parameter, you will have a variable name `em` which will contain value of 1 em in px.

Comment: I'd argue the accepted answer is more useful. This would only provide the `em` value in `px` at the level of where you placed the `div`, if you wanted to get the `px` value deep within a nested DOM tree with `font-size` set at multiple levels you'd have to place test `div`s everywhere. The `getComputedStyle` method seems simpler

Comment: Works beautifully.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something quick and dirty (and based on base font-size of body, not an element), I'd go with:

```
Number(getComputedStyle(document.body,null).fontSize.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''))

 Number(  // Casts numeric strings to number
   getComputedStyle(  // takes element and returns CSSStyleDeclaration object
     document.body,null) // use document.body to get first "styled" element
         .fontSize  // get fontSize property
          .replace(/[^\d]/g, '')  // simple regex that will strip out non-numbers
 ) // returns number
```

Comment: I'd add \. to the regex to account for decimals (then parseFloat() or what not depending on what you gotta do), but this seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution uses binary search and window.matchMedia to find out the em width of a window. We then divide the window em width with the window pixel width to get the final result.
No DOM involved, side-effects free!
In terms of performance it takes around 8 iterations at around 0.2ms on my comp.

```
const singleEmInPixels = getSingleEmInPixels();
console.log(`1em = ${singleEmInPixels}px`);

/**
 * returns the amount of pixels for a single em
 */
function getSingleEmInPixels() {
    let low = 0;
    let high = 200;
    let emWidth = Math.round((high - low) / 2) + low;
    const time = performance.now();
    let iters = 0;
    const maxIters = 10;
    while (high - low > 1) {
        const match = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${emWidth}em)`).matches;
        iters += 1;
        if (match) {
            low = emWidth;
        } else {
            high = emWidth;
        }
        emWidth = Math.round((high - low) / 2) + low;
        if (iters > maxIters) {
            console.warn(`max iterations reached ${iters}`);
            break;
        }
    }
    const singleEmPx = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth / emWidth);
    console.log(`window em width = ${emWidth}, time elapsed =  ${(performance.now() - time)}ms`);
    return singleEmPx;
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I think a problem with the above function may be that there is no way to *set the element* on which you are running it. 1em shifts from context to context. If it were `rem` you'd be g2g.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the em size and this was where I landed. I was inspired by @10011101111's solution to write this general solution. Note, that this may not necessarily be without side-effects as the OP requires, but it may be possible to adapt this to have minimal side effects.

This solution is for those landing here with the same question as I had.

To get a whole-pixel result:

```
function getSize(size = '1em', parent = document.body) {
    let l = document.createElement('div')
    l.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    l.style.boxSize = 'content-box'
    l.style.position = 'absolute'
    l.style.maxHeight = 'none'
    l.style.height = size
    parent.appendChild(l)
    size = l.clientHeight
    l.remove()
    return size
}
```

To get a more precise result:

```
function getSizePrecise(size = '1em', parent = document.body) {
    let l = document.createElement('div'), i = 1, s, t
    l.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    l.style.boxSize = 'content-box'
    l.style.position = 'absolute'
    l.style.maxHeight = 'none'
    l.style.height = size
    parent.appendChild(l)
    t = l.clientHeight
    do {
        s = t
        i *= 10
        l.style.height = 'calc(' + i + '*' + size + ')'
        t = l.clientHeight
    } while(t !== s * 10)
    l.remove()
    return t / i
}
```

Note that you can pass in any size of any unit. For example:

```
getSizePrecise('1ex')
getSizePrecise('1.111ex')
```

You may also be able to adapt this for CSS < 3 compatibility by removing the `calc()` function and directly multiplying the size value except the unit by the multiplier in JavaScript.

If the value overflows, this will probably return 0.

In trying to figure out the overflow limit, I reached the pixel value of 17895696 or 17895697 on Firefox 88.0. So, I updated the above function as follows:

```
function getSizePrecise(size = '1em', parent = document.body) {
    let l = document.createElement('div'), i = 1, s, t
    l.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    l.style.boxSize = 'content-box'
    l.style.position = 'absolute'
    l.style.maxHeight = 'none'
    l.style.height = size
    parent.appendChild(l)
    t = l.clientHeight
    do {
        if (t > 1789569.6)
            break
        s = t
        i *= 10
        l.style.height = 'calc(' + i + '*' + size + ')'
        t = l.clientHeight
    } while(t !== s * 10)
    l.remove()
    return t / i
}
```

The .6 is strictly not necessary (as t will probably be a whole value), but I'm leaving it there for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The following JS function will convert any CSS Length Unit Value to another.
Cheers!

```
// Usage examples: convertCSSLengthUnit('26.556016597510375mm'); convertCSSLengthUnit('26.556016597510375mm', 'px'); convertCSSLengthUnit('100px', 'mm');
function convertCSSLengthUnit(fromUnitValue, toUnit){
  let value = fromUnitValue.match(/[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*/g)[0];
  let unit = fromUnitValue.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[0];

  let frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
    <div style='all: initial; pointer-events: none; display: block; position: absolute; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); color: color: rgba(0,0,0,0); width: 1${unit}; height: 1px;'></div>
  `);
  document.body.appendChild(frag);
  let measureElement = document.body.children[document.body.children.length-1];
  let toUnitValuePixel = measureElement.getBoundingClientRect().width * value; // X
  measureElement.remove();

  if(toUnit){
    let frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
      <div style='all: initial; pointer-events: none; display: block; position: absolute; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); color: color: rgba(0,0,0,0); width: 1${toUnit}; height: 1px;'></div>
    `);
    document.body.appendChild(frag);
    let measureElement = document.body.children[document.body.children.length-1];
    let valueUnit = measureElement.getBoundingClientRect().width; // Y
    measureElement.remove();

    // Given: Aem and Bmm with B=1. We know: Aem = Xpx and Bmm = Ypx. Therefore: 1px = Bmm/Y Result: Aem = Xpx = X * 1px = X * Bmm/Y <=> Aem = X * 1mm/Y (with B=1) <=> Aem = X/Ymm
    return (toUnitValuePixel / valueUnit) + toUnit;
  }
  return toUnitValuePixel + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use this answer below-

```js
parseFloat( getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,null).fontSize )
```

Comment: This is useful, but it gets the value of `1rem`, not `1em`, which is the original question.  `em` units are element-specific.  `rem` units are defined at the document level.  Also, the `, null` is not necessary here.