# Dynamically convert em to px inside of css?

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to know the current em, based on the context, inside of a css style sheet. Is that possible?

I want to calculate the number of pixels for two items: one is in pixels and the other is em:

```
--item-min-width: 250px;
--gap: 3em; (note: this might be different and is not known until runtime)
--max-number-items: 3;
```

Now I need the total width of those three items, plus the gap. Something sort of like this (which of course won't work because I can't add pixels (item-min_width) and em (gap)):

```
@media (min-width: calc(
  var(--max-number-items) * var(--item-min-width) + var(--gap)
))
```

The goal is to convert the gap (3em) to pixels dynamically. Is it possible to figure out the current em of an element?

Comment: You can add pixels and em, you can even add vh units https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMjOzO https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: You cannot use CSS variable inside media query, this is the small drawback of the method of your last question

Comment: @arieljuod Can you post that as an answer please, and I will accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert units, `calc` can handle that:

```
calc(100% + 10px)
calc(2rem - 1%)
calc(var(some-var) + var(another-var))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: you have to note that not all the combination will work, doing `10px + 1` will for example fail because it's invalid. More details here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-type-checking

Answer (score 2):

To get the em value in px. Set default font size for the body (browsers have the default font size of 16px).

**EM value compound with nesting of elements**, refer the MDN docs(link given below).

So, let say you have set the default font size of 16px.

```
1 em = 16px.
```

Now you have a gap of 3em. So 3*16px = 48px.

```
3*250px + 48px = 798px.
```

Please have a look at this article from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems

and this article from w3schools(Set Font Size With Em): https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

Comment: Thanks. However, I am actually trying to ask if CSS can get the current em, contextually. I will update my question.

Comment: I am not able to find anything which can do that. You can get the default font value in JS and convert it into px accordingly. Here is a related question which is using JS for the same.  Have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463518/converting-em-to-px-in-javascript-and-getting-default-font-size