# Magic number in resizing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created code for dragging and resizing an element, as demonstrated in the snippet. First try dragging the div, then mouse up, move the cursor to the right side of the div to get the resize icon to show up. When the resize cursor is showing your can change the width with a mouse drag.

My question is about the -2 in this line:

```
        let newWidth = Math.max(box.width + xChange -2,20);
```

In my real code, the -2 is -18 to make it work.

So my question is what is this magic number related to? Why do I need to subtract 2 in this snippet or 18 in my real code to make the resizing work?

```js
var Obj = {};
Obj.enableDraggables = function (enable, doResize = true) {
//  if (true) return;
//  console.log("enableDraggables: " + enable);
    this.dragSelect = function (e) {
//      console.log("dragSelect");
      Obj.changeCursor = false;
      Obj.dragSrc = this.hasAttribute("dragHandle") ? this.parentNode : this;
      Obj.lastX = e.pageX;
      Obj.lastY = e.pageY;
      //this.style.cursor = "move";
      Obj.dragSrc.style.border = "1px solid black";
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
          if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
            window.getSelection().empty();
          } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
          }
        } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
          document.selection.empty();
        }
      }, 12);
    };
    this.endDragging = function(e) {
      Obj.dragSrc = null;
      this.style.cursor = "default";
      Obj.changeCursor = true;
    };
    this.resizeCursor = function(e) {
      if (!Obj.changeCursor) return;
      if (!e.target.oldCursor) e.target.oldCursor = e.target.style.cursor;
      let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
//      if (Math.abs(e.clientX - rect.right) < 10 && Math.abs(e.clientY - rect.bottom) < 10) {
//        e.target.style.cursor = "se-resize";
      if (Math.abs(e.clientX - rect.right) < 10) {
        e.target.style.cursor = "e-resize";
        document.body.doResize = true;
      } else {
        e.target.style.cursor = e.target.oldCursor;
        document.body.doResize = false;
      }
    }
    this.dragDraggable = function (e) {
      if (!Obj.dragSrc) return;
      
      if (document.body.doResize) {
        let xChange = e.pageX - Obj.lastX;
        let box = Obj.dragSrc.getBoundingClientRect();
        let newWidth = Math.max(box.width + xChange -2,20);
        Obj.dragSrc.style.width = "" + newWidth + "px";
        Obj.lastX = e.pageX;
      } else {
        var isStatic = !Obj.dragSrc.style.position || Obj.dragSrc.style.position == "static";
        var isFixed =  $(Obj.dragSrc).css("position") == "fixed";
        if (isFixed) {
          $(Obj.dragSrc).css("left", parseInt($(Obj.dragSrc).css("left").substring(-2)) + (e.pageX - Obj.lastX) + "px");
          $(Obj.dragSrc).css("top", parseInt($(Obj.dragSrc).css("top").substring(-2)) + (e.pageY - Obj.lastY) + "px");
       
          Obj.dragSrc.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
          Obj.lastX = e.pageX;
          Obj.lastY = e.pageY;
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          return;
        }
        if (isStatic) {
          Obj.dragSrc.style.position = "relative";
          Obj.dragSrc.style.left = "0px";
          Obj.dragSrc.style.top = "0px";

        }
        if (Obj.dragSrc) {
          if (Obj.dragSrc.style.left) {
            var px = parseInt(Obj.dragSrc.style.left.substring(-2));
            var moveTo = (px + (e.pageX - Obj.lastX));
            Obj.lastX = e.pageX;
            Obj.dragSrc.style.left = moveTo + "px";
          } else if (Obj.dragSrc.style.right) {
            var px = parseInt(Obj.dragSrc.style.right.substring(-2));
            var moveTo = (px + (Obj.lastX - e.pageX));
            Obj.lastX = e.pageX;
            Obj.dragSrc.style.right = moveTo + "px";
          }
          if (Obj.dragSrc.style.top) {
            var py = parseInt(Obj.dragSrc.style.top.substring(-2));
            var moveTo = (py + (e.pageY - Obj.lastY));
            Obj.lastY = e.pageY;
            Obj.dragSrc.style.top = moveTo + "px";         
          } else if (Obj.dragSrc.style.bottom) {
            var py = parseInt(Obj.dragSrc.style.bottom.substring(-2));
            var moveTo = (py + (Obj.lastY - e.pageY));
            Obj.lastY = e.pageY;
            Obj.dragSrc.style.bottom = moveTo + "px";         
          }
        }
      }
    };
  if(enable) {
    if (doResize) {
      $(".draggable").on("mousedown", this.dragSelect).on("mousemove", this.resizeCursor).css("cursor", "grab");
    }
    $("body").on("mouseup", this.endDragging);
    $("body").on("mousemove", this.dragDraggable);
  } else {
    $(".draggable").off("mousedown", this.dragSelect);
    $("body").off("mouseup", this.endDragging);
    $("body").off("mousemove", this.dragDraggable);
  }
}

Obj.enableDraggables(true, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">
aa aa aaa bbb ccc aaa dd ddde eeef ffffg gggg hhh hheee ave aev
</div>
```

Comment: That's going to be a nasty one to determine. My assumption would be something around margin/border/padding

Comment: You have 1px borders in the code, so 2 opposite borders gives +-2 px to the final width. I don't know why it's needed to be 18 in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments added to my post, particularly @Stan 's, helped me figure this out.

The prerequisite for this solution was a solution for translating ems to pixels (are there other length measurements). I found a solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463518/converting-em-to-px-in-javascript-and-getting-default-font-size#:~:text=Since%20ems%20measure%20width%20you,truncation%20of%20the%20pixel%20result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463518/converting-em-to-px-in-javascript-and-getting-default-font-size#:%7E:text=Since%20ems%20measure%20width%20you,truncation%20of%20the%20pixel%20result).

In my code, this looks like

```
function getPxs(strVal, elem) {
  if (!elem) elem = document.body;
  let q = strVal[strVal.length -1] == "Q";
  let end = !q ? strVal.substring(strVal.length -2) : strVal.substring(strVal.length -1);
  let num = parseFloat(!q ? strVal.substring(0, strVal.length -2) : strVal.substring(0, strVal.length -1));
  if (end == "px") return num;
  //assuming value is ems. What else could it be?
  if (end == "em") return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elem).fontSize) * num;
  if (end == "in") return 96 * num;
  if (end == "cm") return 37.7952755906 * num;
  if (end == "mm") return 37.7952755906 * num / 10;
  if (q) return 37.7952755906 * num / 40;
  throw Error("Unknown length unit: " + end);
}
```

Then for calculating the offset:

```
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(Sections.dragSrc);
    let offsets = 0;
    offsets += getPxs(style["padding-left"], Sections.dragSrc);
    offsets += getPxs(style["padding-right"], Sections.dragSrc);
    offsets += getPxs(style["border-left-width"], Sections.dragSrc);
    offsets += getPxs(style["border-right-width"], Sections.dragSrc);
    // Margin is not included in element width and height
    //offsets += getPxs(style["margin-left"], Sections.dragSrc);
    //offsets += getPxs(style["margin-right"], Sections.dragSrc);
```

Then `offsets` replaces the magic value